# Python Selenium: Looping through web elements and interacting with them

Tags: python, selenium

This might be confusing to explain, please bear with me.
There is a webpage with x amount of "delete" spans. I have verified that these are the only delete spans on the page. The problems arises when I try to loop through all the delete spans and try to click on each one. Here is basically how I am doing it:

```
deletes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[.='delete']")
for delete in deletes:
    delete.click()
```

Now this will work for the first one, but fails for all the ones past that. I am wondering how I can use this statement:

```
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable([find delete element]))
```

To wait for it to load once again, because a stale element reference exception is thrown.

Comment: when your script click on delete , then what happens ? I suspect that it is a button , so you might be redirected to new page or may be goes to the new tab or new window.

Answer (score 0):

Inside loop wait for first element to be available. i.e.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable([xpath for first delete]))
```

xpath for first delete should be `("//span[.='delete'][1]"`

Alternatively, you can refresh your page after each delete operation.
Next option would be to use try and catch block.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve it. You may use Do-While loop like this to count number of elements, then wait for it, and click it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...
...
while True:
    counter = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[.='delete']"))
    if counter==0:
      break

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable("//span[.='delete']"))
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[.='delete']").click()
```